# Have first column of table a constant width dependent on largest cell width in column

Tags: css

I cannot seem to find a way to do this in pure css, I am looking to have the first column of table a constant width dependent on largest cell width in column.

Example:

```
| Hello | This is a sentence         |
| Foo   | This is a longer sentence  |
```

So the first column containing cells Hello and Foo would have the same width but since its dynamic content I don't want to specify a width.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code.

Comment: Tbh, I am looking for a property for this, it seems basic enough that the browsers would support this, but `table-layout`, etc. doesn't seem to support this. I did a ton of searches and reading of the spec, but I don't see anything.

Comment: You could set the first TD of each row to `width: 0%` and set it's content to `white-space: nowrap` s it tries to be 0% but can't because of the string not wrapping.

Comment: table tr td { border: 1px  solid black } , td in tbale will have auto width - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JqGmrV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is pretty much default behavior. The width of a column matches the size of its content by default. If what you want is to prevent word-wrap within those cells, set `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: hmm, it actually does seem to be the default behavior however its not happening for me in the codebase and I don't see any extra styles being applied, any ideas what would make the columns fall out of alignment?

Comment: you are right this is the default behavior a loose selected class changed the row display type causing the bug..

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, provide border for table, tr and td

By default td width adjusts to cell content

```css
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>This is a sentence</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>This is a longer sentence</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo................</td>
    <td>This is a longer sentence...........</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JqGmrV

Comment: @Eric Hasselbring , please provide css as well which seems to be causing alignment issues